# Split string with fixed first element and second variables elements in c#

Tags: c#, split

My string :

[image]

it would be possible to split this string to two elements

first element

```
mrgar@yahoo.com;
```

and second elments

```
 mrgio@yahoo.com; mrrame@gmail.com;
```

For insert

```
mrgar@yahoo.com;
```

Into table_1 ?

and insert

```
 mrgio@yahoo.com; mrrame@gmail.com;
```

into table_2 ?

the number of element of part one will always be one

the number of elements of part two is variable, it could be one but also 10/100/500

I have tried this code without success

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string value = "mrgar@yahoo.com; mrgio@yahoo.com; mrrame@gmail.com";

        List<string> values = value.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        string Table1 = values[0];
        values.RemoveAt(0);
        string Table2 = string.Join(';', values).Trim();

        Console.WriteLine(Table1);
        Console.WriteLine(Table2);
    }
}
```

need more information?

Comment: Is this beautiful gif related to question or not?

Comment: @Sinatr if not necessary and not appreciated I can eliminate it, no problem.

Comment: I like the coloration of this code. but for some reason I can't select and copy past in order to craft an answer. We live in a time where screen shoot is easier that copy past, so I have to type it? ;)

Comment: Yes, please remove unnecessary parts of the question, they are just noise. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an overload of [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) that takes a maximum number of substrings - just set that to `2`:

```
value = "mrgar@yahoo.com; mrgio@yahoo.com; mrrame@gmail.com;"
string[] values = value.Split(new [] {';'}, 2)
first = values[0]; //mrgar@yahoo.com
rest = values[1];  //mrgio@yahoo.com; mrrame@gmail.com;
```

From there you can trim spaces and/or add semicolons as necessary.